# Liferay - Pages configuration

Tags: javascript, liferay

I'm working with Liferay 7.1.0 GA1. Recently I've tried to add a script in the javascript gap in the pages configuration. When I save the changes, the portal doesn't work correctly and doesn't save the changes.

In console appears the next error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'configureURL' of undefined
```

The script isn't the problem cause it doesn't contain any error. It works perfectly.

Analyzing the logs. this error appears:

```
2021-07-20 07:00:03.155 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3865][PortletServlet:112] javax.portlet.PortletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.LocaleException
javax.portlet.PortletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.LocaleException
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Sorry, I read that everything works until your perfect script comes into play, and only then it breaks. It'd help to see your perfect script (or a [mcve] in order to reproduce and give you a hint. With this level of detail, you're saying "when I do _something_, _something else_ happens. Please read [ask] and edit your question to contain details to reproduce. (and also, GA is followed by another number: Please let us know of the _exact_ Liferay version)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The current version which I´m working is  Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.0 CE GA1. The problem isn´t the script cause I inserted it in others portals and It works perfect. When I analyze the logs this error appears: 2021-07-20 07:00:03.155 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3865][PortletServlet:112] javax.portlet.PortletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.LocaleException

Comment: Unless you specify something else than (figuratively) "When I do _something_ that I feel should be ok, I see this error message", I'm going to vote for this question to be closed, because it lacks _any_ means for anybody to reproduce. Please see [ask] _and edit your question_ with the details. No need to comment again with the same non-details. Also, you might want to update to the latest available 7.1 GA (or even 7.4) to check if you're experiencing a bug that has long been fixed.

Comment: Note: As a _minimum_, you should run a [_patched_ 7.1 GA4](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1)